# How to send a voice call to multiple people with Java and Twilio

Tags: java, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have this method, that makes the request to the specified phone number:

```
    public Call  sendVoiceCall(String responsiblePhoneNumber, String completeName) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);


        String helloTwiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
                .say(new Say.Builder("Whatever")
                        .voice(Say.Voice.ALICE).language(Say.Language.PT_BR).build())
                .build().toXml();

        Call call = Call.creator(
                        new PhoneNumber(responsiblePhoneNumber),
                        new PhoneNumber(twilioPhoneNumber),
                        new Twiml(helloTwiml))
                .create();

        return call;

    }
```

I call it inside this method:

```
@PostMapping("/sendVoiceCall")
    @Transactional
    @Async
    public void sendVoiceCall() {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Optional<User> username = userRepository.findByUsername(auth.getName());

        List<Dependency> uuids = dependencyRepository.returnAllContactUuid(username.orElse(null).getUuid());

        uuids.forEach(contact -> {
            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUuid(contact.getContactUuid());
            voiceCallService.sendVoiceCall(user.orElse(null).getPhone(), username.get().getCompleteName());

        });

        log.info("There was a request to warn users responsible for: " + username.orElse(null).getCompleteName());

    }
```

When I try to send just to one person it works, but when I try to iterate using lambda, it gives me a 200 code and makes nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your API request looks fine to me. Are you definitely getting a list of `uuids`? If it's just returning without making an API requests, then perhaps the list is empty and there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: When I print the value of: user.orElse(null).getPhone(). It prints exactly the phones that I want.

Comment: Are you able to log whether the `sendVoiceCall` method gets called for each of the phone numbers? It seems weird that you would be looping through this code and the API call not happen.

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm really bugged with this one, because with just one, when I'm not looping, it works o.O

Comment: Is the lambda swallowing errors? I notice that the `ACCOUNT_SID`, `AUTH_TOKEN` and `twilioPhoneNumber` aren't defined anywhere. Is there a chance they are out of scope somehow when you call this in a loop with the lambda?

Comment: They are defined into the scope, I just didn't put the values here because they are credentials. But yes, they are working. I'm using it for SMS too, an it works fine

Comment: You're able to send SMS messages in a loop using a lambda like this?

Comment: No, I mean, I haven't tried to. The SMS is just when the user requests.

Comment: So, the issue is the loop and the lambda, you're able to make calls and send messages when not looping. That's why I ask about the scope of the loop itself, also whether the lambda is perhaps swallowing an error somehow? Sorry, I'm not a Java developer, just trying to help you debug this.

Comment: No problem! I really appreciate your help! It doesn't throws any errors. I though that maybe Twilio had some restriction on requests per minute, but I made a sleep, and the same problem is happening. It enters and exists the loop. Very weird, I would say.